# Build Pipeline Plugin & Manual Deployment With Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Let's say I have this situation. I have three jobs. Job number one has two manually triggered downstream jobs (deploy to test, deploy to prod for example). Something like this:

[image]

I want the deployment jobs (test-job-2, test-job-3) to require a password before they are triggered. How can I solve this with Jenkins?

The only option right now supported by the Build Pipeline Plugin is to have a manually deployed downstream job. But this job starts right after you click on it. I would like to require the user to manually enter some parameters (password for example).

Is there some workaround? I was thinking of using the Promoted Builds Plugin. So the deployment jobs would run in a "dry run mode" - just checking that we have ssh access to the server and some other basic stuff. And then in order to deploy you will have to promote the build.

This approach isn't very nice though. Build pipeline and promoted builds plugins don't interact with each other very well.

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19121 Jenkins team claimed that this issue is fixed with Build Pipeline plugin in the plugin version 1.4.5. But seems like it didn't. If you are using a different/newer Jenkins version (core), the latest BPP plugin # 1.4.7 might work. I'm using Jenkins 1.573 and BPP 1.4.7, the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but I guess it would some how solve your problem.

[View Job Filters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters#ViewJobFilters-UserPermissionsforJobs)

Using this feature in tandem with a security feature such as the [Standard matrix based security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup) can help you create a view that will show different jobs depending on who is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I use different Jenkins Servers to "complete the pipeline" using Build Publisher job to publish the last part of the pipeline job to the other jenkins. I then pick it up from there. Operations teams have access to the "prod" jenkins system, and developers have access to the "dev" system.